# Gibt es Regeln fürs Bilden von auszusprechenden Abkürzungen?

Tags: abbreviation

Gibt es Bildungsregeln für Schreibabkürzungen mit Punkt?

Dr., Abb., Stk. sind bekannt, aber wie ist es mit Tischb. für Tischbein, Kolleg. für Kollegen, oder A. für Adler?

Wo sind die Grenzen? Können neue Abkürzungen in der Bundesdeutschen Standardvarietät(?) einfach hinzugebildet werden?

Ich habe in meinen Duden geschaut, dort sind allerlei Abkürzungen beschrieben, aber eine Regel für deren Bildung finde ich nicht.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regeln dafür gibt es nicht - außer vielleicht jener, daß Sprache zur Verständigung dient und dieses Ziel nur erreicht werden kann, wenn sich Sprecher und Zuhörer auf ein gemeinsames Protokoll einigen. Das beinhaltet, daß Abkürzungen, die der Sprecher verwendet, auch dem Zuhörer bekannt sein müssen. Um Niklas Luhmann zu paraphrasieren:

> Kommunikation ist Glückssache - aber sie findet statt.

Ich kann mich erinnern, einmal in einem Projekt gearbeitet zu haben, in welchem ein bestimmter Bürokomplex als "Groga" bezeichnet wurde. Erst viel später fand ich (nicht ortsansässig) heraus, daß die Adresse dieses Komplexes "Große Gallusstraße" lautete und das zu "GroGa" abgekürzt worden war. Njwb. (Naja, wer's braucht.)

Bestimmte Abkürzungen haben sich - allgemein, wie "Stk" für "Stück" oder eben auch nur lokal, wie in meinem Fall - etabliert und werden von den Beteiligten verstanden. Andere hingegen sind nicht etabliert und werden deshalb besser nicht verwendet, wenn man verstanden werden will.

Andererseits ist Sprache lebendig und unterliegt Veränderungen. Abkürzungen etablieren sich oder geraten auch wieder aus der Mode. "S.H." ("Seine Hochwohlgeboren", Anrede männlicher Adressaten in Briefen) wird heute vermutlich kaum noch jemand verstehen, andererseits hätte vermutlich im 19.Jahrhundert bei "MB" niemand auf "Megabyte" getippt.

Comment: Regeln für Abkürzungen gibt es natürlich schon, aber wie du richtig sagst, keine allgemeingültigen und auch keine allgemein gültigen. Z.B. die öffentliche Verwaltung  oder die Bundeswehr geben ganze Wälzer heraus, in denen steht, wie was abzukürzen ist.

Comment: @tofro; ja, genau - das habe ich damit gemeint, daß Sprache der Verständigung dient. Wenn wir beide uns ausmachen, vom nun an "Tisch" zum Stuhl (und vice versa) zu sagen, dann wird das auch funktionieren, genauso wie das Abkürzungsverzeichnis der Verwaltung. Nur Nichteingeweihte werden ein Problem damit haben.